# How to get part of string until certain symbol and then part after symbol as separate values

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, char

What is the good way  for example if I have string:

```
string str = "hello, world = how are you~hello";
```

and my set of  specific symbols allowed in text is: "`=`", "`~`", "`\`", "`.`", "`^`", "`#`"

and if string contains any of this symbols, first get value, or correctly to say, whole exist part of string before specific symbol, and then separately get part of string after specific symbol.

```
hello, world
how are you
hello
```

To attach each for separate variable for first 3 symbols in the string:

```
string part1 = hello, world
string part2 = how are you
string part3 = hello
```

So if string is:

```
  string str = "hello, world = how are you~hello \ ok";
```

result would be:

```
string part1 = hello, world
string part2 = how are you
string part3 = hello \ ok
```

Comment: Write a regular expression that does what you want. If you run into trouble, ask for help on the specific problem you ran into. This isn't a free code-writing service.

Comment: Provide some code then ask question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [overload of string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) that makes this very easy:

```
string str = "hello, world = how are you~hello \\ ok";
var results = str.Split(new [] { '=', '~', '\\', '.', '^', '#'}, 3);

// results[0] = "hello, world "
// results[1] = " how are you"
// results[2] = "hello \ ok"
```

the second parameter is the max number of substrings you want to get.